# Creating transparent video from transparent png files using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, alpha

I have a set of 300 transparent png files and I would like to create a transparent video file from them. I'm using the ffmpeg command as follows:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i anim.%04d.png -r 30 -vcodec png video.webm
```

I know webm has an alpha channel according to [this answer](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23893/make-white-background-in-mp4-movie-transparent). The command creates the video but the transparency is completely lost. What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to create a transparent .mp4 with ffmpeg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify the pixel format, to force it to include the alpha channel, using the [`-pix_fmt` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-Video-options). You don't need to use png as your video codec either.

```
ffmpeg -i anim.%04d.png -r 30  -pix_fmt yuva420p video.webm
```

Comment: What's the complex filter equivalent to `-pix_fmt`? Would `format=yuva420p` be enough?

Comment: Not sure, that might be a good candidate for a new question

Comment: Is it possible to use this for a .mov video file?

Comment: `-pix_fmt yuva420p` not work in `hevc` and `nvenc`.

Comment: alpha isn't supported by hevc and nvenc